# How to use "static data" properly with (Fluent) NHibernate

Tags: c#, design-patterns, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In our database we have "static data" where ids are assigned manually by hand and they are the same through out the whole life of project. In various places, we check if objects have the same ids with these static data such as:

```
public static void UpdateSlotCapacity(MagazineSlot slot)
{
    using (var session = SessionManager.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Lock(slot, LockMode.Upgrade);

        if (slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == 9 || slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == 2 ||
            slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == 3 ||
            slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == 5 || slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == 7)
        {
            Dialogs.ShowInfo("Capacity update is not allowed for " + slot.Card.CardClass.ClassName + " cards");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Although, the data never changes using ids inside the code is really awful and I would like to change this to more readable and maintainable structure. I am thinking about using an `enum` but I am not sure how should I init the enum with fluent nhibernate. Any ideas/tips on how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Please show your code as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that an `enum` would be the better choice.
Here is an example of how you could implement this:

1.Create the enum:

```
public enum CardClassId {
    ClassA = 1,
    ClassB = 2,
    ClassC = 3,
    ...
}
```

2.Change the type of the **ClassId** property from *int* to *CardClassId*:

```
public virtual CardClassId ClassId { get; set; }
```

3.Change your mapping (if it's not already like this):

```
Id(x => x.ClassId).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

4.Change your code, so it would look like this:

```
public static void UpdateSlotCapacity(MagazineSlot slot)
    {
        using (var session = SessionManager.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Lock(slot, LockMode.Upgrade);

            if (slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == CardClassId.ClassI ||
                slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == CardClassId.ClassB ||
                slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == CardClassId.ClassC ||
                slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == CardClassId.ClassE ||
                slot.Card.CardClass.ClassId == CardClassId.ClassG)
            {
                Dialogs.ShowInfo("Capacity update is not allowed for " + slot.Card.CardClass.ClassName + " cards");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

You don't need to worry that much about the mapping, because NHibernate will cast from the database integer to your enum automatically. Just keep in mind that you must set the **GeneratedBy** to *Assigned*, and that your enum items should have its values set to the same values that's in your database.